# fluent nhibernate nullable foreign key "null reference exception"

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have just started with nHibernate Fluent and all is going well with my associations, until I hit a location that have a StateID (which is a foreign key, see below) of null. Then I get an error **"null reference exception"**

on this line **Console.WriteLine(location.address + ", " + location.State.state);**

below:

```
public static void LoadLocationsFromDatabase()
{
    using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        // retreive all stores and display them
        using (session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var locations = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Location))
                .List<Location>();

            var i = 0;
            foreach (var location in locations)
            {
                i++;
                Console.WriteLine(location.address + ", " + location.State.state);
            }
        }

    }
}

public LocationMap()
{
    Id(x => x.locationID).Column("ID");
    Map(x => x.address).Column("Address");
    References(x => x.State)
  .Column("StateID")
      .Cascade.All();
}

public class State
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual String state { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

I guess this value might shouldn't probably be null in the DB. StateID is a foreign key to ID on the states table, so I guess it shouldn't be allowed to be null?

Anyway I feel that my code should be able to allow for this one way or another, so how can I get around this?

Comment: Can State be null in Location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(location.address + ", " + (location.State == null ? "Unknown" : location.State.state));
```

Comment: you're a legend. Thanks very much